# PHP 5.3 autoloader

Tags: php, autoload, psr-0

I would like to use the PSR-0 Standard way to autoload classes without requiring to add includes, e.g. how can I replace the code below with the autoloading mechanism:

```
namespace Example;
use MyLib\Controller;
include_once './library/MyLib/Controller/AbstractController.php';
class MyController extends Controller\AbstractController {
[...]
```

So in the example above, it shows that in every controllers I need to include the abstract controller, which is crazy...

I have found the PSR-0 code here:

https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

https://gist.github.com/221634

But I have no idea how I need to implement this in my application.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need include (include/require statement) the file with the autoloader code in the first script of your application

If you choose for use the Composer's autoloader as @Skpd said then you should have a code like this in the top of your first PHP script.

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/composer_autoloader.php'

$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
$loader->add('MyLib', __DIR__.'/library/');
$loader->register();
```

If you decide to use Composer as your vendor manager then add your custom namespaces to your `composer.json` and include `vendor/autoload.php`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use autoloader. There is example class loader from Composer:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of Composer.
 *
 * (c) Nils Adermann <naderman@naderman.de>
 *     Jordi Boggiano <j.boggiano@seld.be>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Composer\Autoload;

/**
 * ClassLoader implements a PSR-0 class loader
 *
 * See https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md
 *
 *     $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
 *
 *     // register classes with namespaces
 *     $loader->add('Symfony\Component', __DIR__.'/component');
 *     $loader->add('Symfony',           __DIR__.'/framework');
 *
 *     // activate the autoloader
 *     $loader->register();
 *
 *     // to enable searching the include path (eg. for PEAR packages)
 *     $loader->setUseIncludePath(true);
 *
 * In this example, if you try to use a class in the Symfony\Component
 * namespace or one of its children (Symfony\Component\Console for instance),
 * the autoloader will first look for the class under the component/
 * directory, and it will then fallback to the framework/ directory if not
 * found before giving up.
 *
 * This class is loosely based on the Symfony UniversalClassLoader.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 * @author Jordi Boggiano <j.boggiano@seld.be>
 */
class ClassLoader
{
    private $prefixes = array();
    private $fallbackDirs = array();
    private $useIncludePath = false;
    private $classMap = array();

    public function getPrefixes()
    {
        return $this->prefixes;
    }

    public function getFallbackDirs()
    {
        return $this->fallbackDirs;
    }

    public function getClassMap()
    {
        return $this->classMap;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $classMap Class to filename map
     */
    public function addClassMap(array $classMap)
    {
        if ($this->classMap) {
            $this->classMap = array_merge($this->classMap, $classMap);
        } else {
            $this->classMap = $classMap;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers a set of classes
     *
     * @param string       $prefix The classes prefix
     * @param array|string $paths  The location(s) of the classes
     */
    public function add($prefix, $paths)
    {
        if (!$prefix) {
            foreach ((array) $paths as $path) {
                $this->fallbackDirs[] = $path;
            }

            return;
        }
        if (isset($this->prefixes[$prefix])) {
            $this->prefixes[$prefix] = array_merge(
                $this->prefixes[$prefix],
                (array) $paths
            );
        } else {
            $this->prefixes[$prefix] = (array) $paths;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Turns on searching the include path for class files.
     *
     * @param bool $useIncludePath
     */
    public function setUseIncludePath($useIncludePath)
    {
        $this->useIncludePath = $useIncludePath;
    }

    /**
     * Can be used to check if the autoloader uses the include path to check
     * for classes.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getUseIncludePath()
    {
        return $this->useIncludePath;
    }

    /**
     * Registers this instance as an autoloader.
     *
     * @param bool $prepend Whether to prepend the autoloader or not
     */
    public function register($prepend = false)
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'), true, $prepend);
    }

    /**
     * Unregisters this instance as an autoloader.
     */
    public function unregister()
    {
        spl_autoload_unregister(array($this, 'loadClass'));
    }

    /**
     * Loads the given class or interface.
     *
     * @param  string    $class The name of the class
     * @return bool|null True, if loaded
     */
    public function loadClass($class)
    {
        if ($file = $this->findFile($class)) {
            include $file;

            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds the path to the file where the class is defined.
     *
     * @param string $class The name of the class
     *
     * @return string|null The path, if found
     */
    public function findFile($class)
    {
        if ('\\' == $class[0]) {
            $class = substr($class, 1);
        }

        if (isset($this->classMap[$class])) {
            return $this->classMap[$class];
        }

        if (false !== $pos = strrpos($class, '\\')) {
            // namespaced class name
            $classPath = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, substr($class, 0, $pos)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            $className = substr($class, $pos + 1);
        } else {
            // PEAR-like class name
            $classPath = null;
            $className = $class;
        }

        $classPath .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

        foreach ($this->prefixes as $prefix => $dirs) {
            if (0 === strpos($class, $prefix)) {
                foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
                    if (file_exists($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $classPath)) {
                        return $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $classPath;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->fallbackDirs as $dir) {
            if (file_exists($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $classPath)) {
                return $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $classPath;
            }
        }

        if ($this->useIncludePath && $file = stream_resolve_include_path($classPath)) {
            return $file;
        }

        return $this->classMap[$class] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's already nice autoloader linked in question, the problem here is that OP does not know how to use it and how to properly set directory structure to work with psr-0 autoloader.